# I am unable to run my python code and get "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Tags: python, python-2.7, jvm

I am newbie to python & want to run simple helloworld program,

here is my default.py

```
from quickstart import HelloWorld
import jpype
import os.path
asd= os.path.join(os.path.abspath("./"), "lib")

jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.ext.dirs=%s" % asd)

hw = HelloWorld()
hw.main()
```

and here is my code in *init*.py

```
class HelloWorld:

def __init__(self, dataDir):
    self.dataDir = dataDir

def main(self):
    """
        : The path to the documents directory. :
    """

    Document = jpype.JClass("com.aspose.words.Document")

    DocumentBuilder = jpype.JClass("com.aspose.words.DocumentBuilder")

    doc = Document()
    builder = DocumentBuilder(doc)

    builder.writeln('Hello World!')
    doc.save(self.dataDir +'HelloWorld.docx')
```

The problem is when I run above code I dont get any error but program stopped with this message "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)",

Comment: Is this the indentation in your init.py file? It is wrong!

Comment: I'm curious why you're using a Java library, instead of something like https://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/  - seems like it's not a 'simple' hello world! :)

Comment: Yeah I know but there is no indentation error, If there is indentation error pycharm let me know

Comment: Then you should correct the indentation in your question

Comment: I am using java library because I want to run it with javabridge

Comment: same indentation is in init.py with no error